# How do I verify canceled in-app subscription?

Tags: java, android, in-app-billing, android-developer-api, in-app-subscription

I am using: bp.isSubscribed(ID) to verify my subscription. But when I cancel a subscription the method bp.isSubscribed(ID) still returning true. What should I do?

transDetails.purchaseInfo.purchaseData.purchaseState.toString() 
Always return PurchasedSuccessfully after i cancelled manually from  play store manage subscription.

```
public void checkSubscriptionDetails(){

bp = new BillingProcessor(this, LICENSE_KEY, new BillingProcessor.IBillingHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onProductPurchased(@NonNull String productId, @Nullable TransactionDetails details) {

                Common.printLog("InApp", ":onProductPurchased :" + productId);


            }

            @Override
            public void onPurchaseHistoryRestored() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onBillingError(int errorCode, @Nullable Throwable error) {
           }

            @Override
            public void onBillingInitialized() {


            }
        });


boolean purchaseResult = bp.loadOwnedPurchasesFromGoogle();
// ## purchaseResult is always return FALSE 

        if (bp.isSubscribed(planID)) {

            TransactionDetails transDetails = bp.getSubscriptionTransactionDetails(planID);

            String strDetailsSubsMonth = "OrderID:" + transDetails.orderId +
                    "\nproductId: " + transDetails.productId +
                    "\npurchaseToken: " + transDetails.purchaseToken +
                    "\npurchaseTime: " + transDetails.purchaseTime +
                    "\npurchaseInfo.signature: " + transDetails.purchaseInfo.signature +
                    "\npurchaseInfo.responseData: " + transDetails.purchaseInfo.responseData +
                    "\npurchaseData.purchaseToken: " + transDetails.purchaseInfo.purchaseData.purchaseToken +
                    "\npurchaseData.autoRenewing: " + transDetails.purchaseInfo.purchaseData.autoRenewing +
                    "\npurchaseData.developerPayload: " + transDetails.purchaseInfo.purchaseData.developerPayload +
                    "\npurchaseData.purchaseState: " + transDetails.purchaseInfo.purchaseData.purchaseState.toString();

            String strPurchaseState = transDetails.purchaseInfo.purchaseData.purchaseState.toString();
            Common.printLog("InApp", "Details: " + planID + " >> " + strDetailsSubsMonth + " \n" + "Purchase State :" + strPurchaseState);
        }

}


package com.anjlab.android.iab.v3;

public enum PurchaseState
{
    PurchasedSuccessfully,
    Canceled,
    Refunded,
    SubscriptionExpired
}
```

i need return "Canceled" when subscription canceled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best Solution from Server side get actual information for subscription or you can cross verify by Node.js configuration.

https://caster.io/lessons/verify-android-app-subscription-status-from-nodejs

Answer (score 1):

Initiate `bp` varibale in `onCreate()` and then call `loadOwnedPurchasesFromGoogle()`.

> In my case!

Don't know why we need to Call `loadOwnedPurchasesFromGoogle()` for multiple time. I always get false when I call in `loadOwnedPurchasesFromGoogle()` in `onCreate()`. But when I call in `onPause()` and `onDestory()`, I get true and my all values get update.

After getting `loadOwnedPurchasesFromGoogle()` true, I get update subscription value!

Comment: Thanks i got update data but i notice only update
 "autoRenewing": true/false after cancel

**but not get updated value after auto renew plan.
- orderId
- purchaseTime**


```{
  "orderId": "GPA.3346-XXXXX",
  "packageName": "XXXXX",
  "productId": "monthly",
  "purchaseTime": 1570265452385,
  "purchaseState": 0,
  "developerPayload": "subs:xxxxxx",
  "purchaseToken": "**************",
  "autoRenewing": false
 }```

Comment: How to get also more data in application side like as??

`{
    "kind": "androidpublisher#subscriptionPurchase",
    "startTimeMillis": "1569992364817",
    "expiryTimeMillis": "1569992959731",
    "autoRenewing": false,
    "priceCurrencyCode": "XXX",
    "priceAmountMicros": "XXXXX",
    "countryCode": "IN",
    "developerPayload": "subs:monthly",
    "paymentState": 1,
    "cancelReason": 0,
    "userCancellationTimeMillis": "1569992810284",
    "orderId": "GPA.XXXX-XXX-7672-59220..0",
    "purchaseType": 0,
    "acknowledgementState": 1
}`

Comment: The value will be update after cancellation of subscription and user purchase the subscription again!
On auto-renew, value doesn't update.

If this answer is helpful for you kindly accept as Answer.